# Automate Windows Sandbox using Powershell modules

Tags: windows, powershell, security, sandbox, malware

I want to automate the Windows Sandbox application and achieve a bunch of operations like network setup, coping files, execution in privilege, tools installation, backup mechanism, snapshot/rollback options and so forth.

According to the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview), all the steps has executed to install/enable a sandbox component into Windows 11 pro (build : 22H2 - 22621.1413) OS version.

```
Installation steps:

1. Open the Start menu and type "Windows Features" in the search box.
2. Click on "Turn Windows features on or off".
3. Scroll down to find "Windows Sandbox" in the list of features, and check the box next to it.
4. Click "OK" and wait for Windows to install the feature.
5. Restart the system
```

Now to automate the noted task using scripts, I'm looking at some popular and robust powershell modules which will give me the entire control of Windows-Sandbox.

Can anyone suggest some advance scripting modules to gain control over Windows-Sandbox ?